# Sharepoint 2013 custom standard UI icons

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i'm currently building up a design-solution-feature for SP13. it deploys master pages, layouts, css files etc.

my question is: is there actually any way to implement custom standard UI icons? e.g.: for the ribbonrow or settings icon on the top right corner?

it would be perfect if i could just overwrite the generated themedpng with a custom one (same dimensions of course) via code (event receiver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it, but none of them is the perfect solution.

1- Backup "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\spcommon.png" and replace it with your own file.

This is not recommended because you should not touch SharePoint files. 
It could be overwritten when installing a SharePoint update. 
But it is an easy solution which is used sometimes in the real world.

2- You can use jquery (or javascript) to replace all references to "/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png" by your own image once the page is loaded. You can deploy your image on your site.

Problem is the out of the box image will be displayed first and then replaced by your image. So there will be a very short time were the old image will be displayed.

Comment: thx for your reply - 1st option isn't one for me - will see what i can do with 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

this script included in the masterpage did it for me:

```
    var CustomIcons = function () {

    var site_url;

    if (_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl === "/") {
        site_url = "";
    } else {
        site_url = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
    }

    var commom_img_url = site_url + '/_layouts/15/images/spcommon-custom.png';
    var commom_img_url2 = site_url + '/_layouts/15/images/spcommon-custom2.png';
    var help_img_url = site_url + '/_layouts/15/images/help.png';
    var settings_img_url = site_url + '/_layouts/15/images/settings.png';

    $('#siteactiontd').find('img:first').attr('src', settings_img_url);
    $('#ms-help').find('img:first').attr('src', help_img_url);
    $('#ctl00_SyncPromotedAction').find('img:first').attr('src', commom_img_url);
    $('#ctl00_fullscreenmodeBtn').find('img:first').attr('src', commom_img_url);
    $('a[_action="edit"]').find('img:first').attr('src', commom_img_url);
    $('a[_action="save"]').find('img:first').attr('src', commom_img_url2);
}
```